# How to grep the content of one file from a list of zipped files (.gz)

Tags: unix

How to grep the content of one file  from a list of zipped files (.gz)

i tried zgrep -f <(awk -F"|" '{print $1}' PATTERNFILE.dat) TARGETFILES*gz command but the pattern is getting search in just one file from the target file list -Assuming i have 50  .gz files

Answer (score 0):

Use "xargs" command to iterate over the files:

Reference https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html